# Microsoft Silverlight run in out of browser

Tags: silverlight

I installed silverlight3 tools.But I dont Know how to run in out of browser.Please tel me the procedure to run out of browser.

Answer (score 2):

(1) Create a new or (2) Open the Silverlight application using Visual Studio 2008/2010. From the Solution Explorer, simply right-click the Project file, Properties, and the Properties page will show up. Under the Silverlight tab, check 'Enable running application out of the browser'.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i enabled all those options and installed silverlight tools for 2008 also but i didnt get it

Comment: @arpitha: make sure it's Silverlight Tools for Visual Studio 2008 SP1 you are installing.